# How to spawn a custom CLI prompt after login to a linux machine using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm doing a CLI hobby project in linux machine which will allow the user to execute only custom commands. Currently if the user login to the linux machine using SSH it is landing in the shell prompt. Instead i want the user to land in my own CLI prompt.

Is there any SSHD config available to spawn a our own binary upon successful login?

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: why not change the login shell? Why not add a command to `.bashrc` or its equivalent?

Comment: @NicoHaase i didn't think about this option. Will try it out.

Comment: Hint: have a look at your `/etc/passwd` file to see how it could be done.

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks a lot. I have added my binary name at the top of the .bashrc file and achieved what i want.